How to find (power) distribution parameters
There is a set of values (vector, array), it is expected that they have a distribution of $Ax^D$ type, where D < 0, and $x_i$ are in the range [m;M] (range [0;∞) is impossible - the integral diverges...). The task is to find these parameters (D, m, M). At least — parameter D.
I tried to estimate D by estimating the mean value of x (comparing it with the theoretical one obtained by integration), and as an estimate of m and M I took just the minimum and maximum values from the initial set. It seemed, that it turns out something similar to the truth, but for reliability I generated several own test sets for different D, and I got a very large discrepancy with the truth (like, for -1 I get -0.9, for -3 - -2.2).
I searched the Internet and came across the maximum likelihood method, but I don't understand whether it is or not, + how exactly to apply it to this problem.
As an option, I thought to search for the value of χ² for different D and take the D for which it is minimal, but I haven't implemented it yet, because on the one hand, minimizing such a complex function is still such a problem, and on the other hand, it is necessary to divide the whole range into several areas - and how many exactly? How exactly to choose the number of degrees of freedom?
Just in case the power distribution hypothesis is incorrect, what is the general approach to solving such problems?
In short, I would be grateful to matstatisticians for advice....

The maximum likelihood methods is really exactly what it says - you take the likelihood and maximize it. For numerical reasons, it is usually better to maximize the log-likelihood instead (which finds the same maxima).
In your case, the likelihood for a single point is just $Ax^D$ (where $A$ is in fact a function of $m, M, D$). The total likelihood is the product of the individual likelihoods $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, m, M, D) = \prod A x_i^D$ so you are optimizing over $m,M,D$ to gain the highest value.
You can note that for $m_1 < m_2 \leq \min x_i$ and fixed $M, D$ you'll always have $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, m_1, M, D) < \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, m_2, M, D)$, i.e.  the maximum likelihood is obtained precisely when $m, M$ are the bounds of observed data. This simplifies the problem (you just need to optimize $D$), but is typically unrealistic, so you may want to add some regularization/prior term to penalize too tight bounds.

Thank you! And how would you recommend to solve this problem numerically (I am a C++ programmer)? What methods? Gradient descent?

Yes, gradient descent would be the typical choice.

I'm sorry, but there's another question. I started working, I wrote down a logarithmic likelihood function. The maximum condition is that the derivatives of the parameters are zero. But this condition immediately leads me to M=0 (m=0). Where did I make a mistake? My calculations are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14HjxFS_LGsLvDs20mxQcfYkEbmxQb6dm/view?usp=sharing

One problem I see is that you ignore bounds - the likelihood of any datapoint outside $[m,M]$ needs to be zero. In other words, you can effectively optimize only over $m \leq \min x_i, M \geq \max x_i$, because zero cannot be the maximum likelihood. Also with my quick checks, I don't think you can get the maximum analytically for $D$.

I'm not trying to solve analytically. I was just writing down a function to implement in code (and possibly its gradient).
The solution (using the ALGLIB library) does not give any result, as expected. Even if I limit the values of m and M to the minimum and maximum values of x respectively.
When writing the function analytically, there is no connection to the specific data, moreover, I cannot limit the value of M, because for it the difference from the maximum value is large, and thus we will get large distortions.

I am not sure I understand your concerns. Let me restate - the distribution for your values (and thus the likelihood as well) is implicitly defined as $0$ if $x < m$ or $x > M$ and $Ax^D$ otherwise. I.e. it is discontinous at $m,M$. You can then analytically show that fixing any $D$, you obtain maximum likelihood by choosing $m,M$ as bounds of the observed data. This leaves you with optimizing $D$. For example observing $1,2,3$, my calculations give that maximum likelihood is obtained with $m = 1, M = 3, D \simeq -0.521$ - giving you $A \simeq 0.691$.
